# Kibana Dashboard version control?

Tags: azure-devops, version-control, kibana

I am using Azure DevOps for my source control. I am creating Kibana Dashboard and wondering if it can be source control as well using Azure DevOps. My idea is:

- Create Repo in Azure DevOps.
- Write automated script(code) so it saves current Kibana Dashboard Saved Object into Azure DevOps.

In this way, I have old Dashboard in the repo. Has anyone done this? It doesn't have to be Azure DevOps, if you have any experience with it, please share with me. I am new to version control.

(https://docs.logz.io/api/cookbook/backing-up-kibana-objects-to-github.html < this was using github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Kibana Dashboard version control?

The first thing to point out is that Azure devops is not a version control tool. It provides developer services to support teams to plan work, collaborate on code development, and build and deploy applications. Developers can work in the cloud using Azure DevOps Services or on-premises using Azure DevOps Server.

And Azure repo supports two types of version control methods: `Git` (distributed) and Team Foundation Version Control (`TFVC`):

[What is source control?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/source-control?view=azure-devops)

You could set the version control type when you create the project:

[image]

After that, we could get the URL of the repo is also a git repo:

[image]

Git in Visual Studio and Azure DevOps is **standard Git**, **github is the same**.

So, that document also applies to azure devops, we just need to replace the github repo link to the azure devops repo link.

> In this way, I have old Dashboard in the repo. Has anyone done this?

If you have old Dashboard in the azure devops repo, just clone the old json files to the local and update the json files and push it to the azure devops by git command line. Or you could modify the json files in the azure devops repo UI directly.

So, for the azure devops, you just need to make sure the Version control of your repo is `git`, and then you can handle azure repo like git.